# VBA Error in Access: "The cammand or action 'RecordsGoToNew' isn't available now"

Tags: ms-access, vba

I would like to apologize in advance. The form I am dealing with is very complicated with many moving parts so I am sorry it my explanations aren't clear.

I have a form that contains many subforms. One particular subform, fAdminToolsDetails, has a subform of its own:sfAdminToolsYearly. Depending on the state of the overall form, different queries and tables will populate the forms with information. I designed the states with use of an enum . Depending on which enum value is passed into the sub the state will change and the appropriate record sources, control sources, and so on are updated. However, the previously mentioned form, sfAdminToolsYearly, does not update correctly. Its information still reflects that of the previous state until a user interacts with its parent: fAdminToolsDetails.

I personally this this is fine. However, my client is concerned this might cause some confusion. In order to rectify this issue I attempted to tell the form to go to a new record, just to clear out all the data as well as create a new option or record addition. However, I receive the error in the title for all states except DEPARTMENT.

I have been looking at this all day and can't seem to find the root cause of the error. Please look at my code below and see if you can help. The error is initially thrown on the very last line.

Please let me know if there are any questions about the code. I will be happy to answer them.

Thank You

```
Private Function changeState(ByVal state As EnumState, ByVal CrrntId As Long)

Dim prevSub As String
Dim level As String
Dim lvlSub As String
Dim prevLvl As String
Dim fYrIndex As Integer
Dim crrntDeptIndex As Integer
Dim crrntDivIndex As Integer
Dim crrntSDivIndex As Integer
Dim crrntSSDivIndex As Integer
Dim crrntSSSDivIndex As Integer

Me![crrntDept].SetFocus
crrntDeptIndex = Me![crrntDept].ListIndex

Me![crrntDiv].SetFocus
crrntDivIndex = Me![crrntDiv].ListIndex

Me![crrntSDiv].SetFocus
crrntSDivIndex = Me![crrntSDiv].ListIndex

Me![crrntSSDiv].SetFocus
crrntSSDivIndex = Me![crrntSSDiv].ListIndex

Me![crrntSSSDiv].SetFocus
crrntSSSDivIndex = Me![crrntSSSDiv].ListIndex

crrntState = state

Dim selectStatement As String

Select Case state

    Case DEPARTMENT

        level = "Department"
        lvlSub = "Dept"
        prevLvl = vbNullString
        prevSub = vbNullString





    Case DIVISION

        level = "Division"
        lvlSub = "Div"
        prevSub = "Dept"
        prevLvl = "Department"

        Me.fAdminToolsDetails.Form.sfAdminToolsYearly![sectionNumber].ControlSource = "DivYearly_SectionNum"
        Me.fAdminToolsDetails.Form.sfAdminToolsYearly![SectionNumberLabel].Caption = "Division Number"
        Me.fAdminToolsDetails.Form.sfAdminToolsYearly![tbNumbersPages].Visible = True


        If CrrntId = -1 Then
            CrrntId = Me!Dept_ID

        End If

    Case SUBDIVISION
            level = "SubDivision"
            lvlSub = "SubDiv"
            prevSub = "Div"
            prevLvl = "Division"

            Me.fAdminToolsDetails.Form.sfAdminToolsYearly![sectionNumber].ControlSource = "SubDivYearly_ParaNum"
            Me.fAdminToolsDetails.Form.sfAdminToolsYearly![SectionNumberLabel].Caption = "Subdivision Letter"

            If CrrntId = -1 Then
                 CrrntId = Me!Div_Id

            End If

     Case SUBSUBDIVISION
            level = "SubSubDivision"
            lvlSub = "SubSubDiv"
            prevSub = "SubDiv"
            prevLvl = "SubDivision"

            Me.fAdminToolsDetails.Form.sfAdminToolsYearly![sectionNumber].ControlSource = "SubSubDivYearly_SubParaNum"
            Me.fAdminToolsDetails.Form.sfAdminToolsYearly![SectionNumberLabel].Caption = "SubSubdivision Number"

            If CrrntId = -1 Then
                 CrrntId = Me!SubDiv_ID

            End If

    Case SUBSUBSUBDIVISION
            level = "SubSubSubDivision"
            lvlSub = "SubSubSubDiv"
            prevSub = "SubSubDiv"
            prevLvl = "SubSubDivision"

            Me.fAdminToolsDetails.Form.sfAdminToolsYearly![sectionNumber].ControlSource = "SubSubSubDivYearly_SubSectionNum"
            Me.fAdminToolsDetails.Form.sfAdminToolsYearly![SectionNumberLabel].Caption = "SubSubSubdivision Letter"

            If CrrntId = -1 Then
                 CrrntId = Me!SubSubDiv_ID

            End If

End Select

Me![lvlSub].ControlSource = "='" & lvlSub & "'"

Me.sfListOfLvlData.LinkChildFields = vbNullString
Me.sfListOfLvlData.LinkMasterFields = vbNullString

Me.fAdminToolsDetails.LinkMasterFields = vbNullString
Me.fAdminToolsDetails.LinkChildFields = vbNullString

If state <> DEPARTMENT Then

    Me.RecordSource = "SELECT DISTINCT " & prevLvl & "." & prevSub & "_ID FROM " & prevLvl & " WHERE " & prevLvl & "." & prevSub & "_ID = " & CrrntId
    Me.sfListOfLvlData.Form.RecordSource = "SELECT DISTINCT " & level & "." & lvlSub & "_ID, " & level & "." & lvlSub & "_Short_Name, " & level & "Yearly." & prevSub & "_ID FROM " & level & " " & _
    "INNER JOIN " & level & "Yearly ON " & level & "." & lvlSub & "_ID=" & level & "Yearly." & lvlSub & "_ID" & " ORDER BY " & level & "." & lvlSub & "_Short_Name"
    Me.sfListOfLvlData.LinkChildFields = prevSub & "_ID"
    Me.sfListOfLvlData.LinkMasterFields = prevSub & "_ID"
Else


    Me.sfListOfLvlData.Form.RecordSource = "SELECT " & level & "." & lvlSub & "_ID, " & level & "." & lvlSub & "_Short_Name FROM " & level & " ORDER BY " & lvlSub & "_Short_Name"
    Me.sfListOfLvlData.LinkChildFields = vbNullString
    Me.RecordSource = level
    Me.sfListOfLvlData.LinkMasterFields = vbNullString

End If




Me![Title].ControlSource = "='" & level & "'"
Me.sfListOfLvlData.Form![ShortName].ControlSource = lvlSub & "_Short_Name"
Me![parentId].ControlSource = prevSub & "_ID"

Me.fAdminToolsDetails.Form.sfAdminToolsYearly![Yearly_Year].SetFocus

If Not state = DIVISION Then

    Me.fAdminToolsDetails.Form.sfAdminToolsYearly![tbNumbersPages].Visible = False

End If


If Not state = DEPARTMENT Then







    Me.fAdminToolsDetails![COFRSCode].Visible = False
    Me.fAdminToolsDetails![functArea].Visible = False
    Me.fAdminToolsDetails![chbOperatingBudget].Visible = False
    Me.fAdminToolsDetails![chbCapitalBudget].Visible = False

    Me.fAdminToolsDetails.Form.sfAdminToolsYearly![sectionNumber].Visible = True
    Me.fAdminToolsDetails.Form.sfAdminToolsYearly![tabDirectors].Visible = False
    Me.fAdminToolsDetails.Form.sfAdminToolsYearly![Parent].Visible = True
    Me.fAdminToolsDetails.Form.sfAdminToolsYearly![Parent].RowSource = "SELECT " & prevLvl & "." & prevSub & "_Short_Name, " & prevLvl & "." & prevSub & "_ID " & _
                                                                            "FROM " & prevLvl & " " & _
                                                                            "ORDER BY " & prevLvl & "." & prevSub & "_Short_Name"
    Me.fAdminToolsDetails.Form.sfAdminToolsYearly![Parent].ControlSource = prevSub & "_ID"




Else

    Me.fAdminToolsDetails![COFRSCode].Visible = True
    Me.fAdminToolsDetails![functArea].Visible = True
    Me.fAdminToolsDetails![chbOperatingBudget].Visible = True
    Me.fAdminToolsDetails![chbCapitalBudget].Visible = True

    Me.fAdminToolsDetails.Form.sfAdminToolsYearly![tabDirectors].Visible = True
    Me.fAdminToolsDetails.Form.sfAdminToolsYearly![Parent].Visible = False
    Me.fAdminToolsDetails.Form.sfAdminToolsYearly![sectionNumber].Visible = False

End If
Me.mainID.ControlSource = "=[sfListOfLvlData]![" & lvlSub & "_ID]"

Me.fAdminToolsDetails.Form.RecordSource = level
Me.fAdminToolsDetails.LinkMasterFields = "mainID"
Me.fAdminToolsDetails.LinkChildFields = lvlSub & "_ID"
Me.fAdminToolsDetails![Name].ControlSource = lvlSub & "_Name"
Me.fAdminToolsDetails![Short_Name].ControlSource = lvlSub & "_Short_Name"
Me.fAdminToolsDetails![Cd].ControlSource = lvlSub & "_Cd"
Me.fAdminToolsDetails![Active].ControlSource = lvlSub & "_Active"
 Me.fAdminToolsDetails![Id].ControlSource = lvlSub & "_ID"

Me.fAdminToolsDetails![lstItemByYear].RowSource = "SELECT " & level & "Yearly." & lvlSub & "Yearly_Id, " & level & "Yearly." & lvlSub & "Yearly_Year" & _
                                                    " FROM " & level & "Yearly" & _
                                                    " WHERE (((" & level & "Yearly." & lvlSub & "_ID) = [Forms]![testAdminForm]![mainID])) " & _
                                                    "ORDER BY " & level & "Yearly." & lvlSub & "Yearly_Year"


Me.fAdminToolsDetails.Form.sfAdminToolsYearly.Form.RecordSource = level & "Yearly"
Me.fAdminToolsDetails.Form.sfAdminToolsYearly.LinkMasterFields = "Yearly_Id"
Me.fAdminToolsDetails.Form.sfAdminToolsYearly.LinkChildFields = lvlSub & "Yearly_ID"

Me.fAdminToolsDetails.Form.sfAdminToolsYearly![Yearly_Id].ControlSource = lvlSub &          "Yearly_ID"
Me.fAdminToolsDetails.Form.sfAdminToolsYearly![Parent_Id].ControlSource = lvlSub & "_ID"
Me.fAdminToolsDetails.Form.sfAdminToolsYearly![Yearly_Year].ControlSource = lvlSub & "Yearly_Year"
Me.fAdminToolsDetails.Form.sfAdminToolsYearly![Yearly_Order].ControlSource = lvlSub & "Yearly_Order"
Me.fAdminToolsDetails.Form.sfAdminToolsYearly![Yearly_Name].ControlSource = lvlSub & "Yearly_Name"
Me.fAdminToolsDetails.Form.sfAdminToolsYearly![Yearly_FDesc].ControlSource = lvlSub & "Yearly_FDesc"
Me.fAdminToolsDetails.Form.sfAdminToolsYearly![Yearly_SDesc].ControlSource = lvlSub & "Yearly_SDesc"


Me![crrntDept].SetFocus
Me.crrntDept = Me.crrntDept.ItemData(crrntDeptIndex)

Me![crrntDiv].SetFocus
Me.crrntDiv = Me.crrntDiv.ItemData(crrntDivIndex)

Me![crrntSDiv].SetFocus
Me.crrntSDiv = Me.crrntSDiv.ItemData(crrntSDivIndex)

Me![crrntSSDiv].SetFocus
Me.crrntSSDiv = Me.crrntSSDiv.ItemData(crrntSSDivIndex)

Me.fAdminToolsDetails.Form.sfAdminToolsYearly.SetFocus
Me.fAdminToolsDetails.Form.sfAdminToolsYearly.Form.AllowAdditions = True
' Me.fAdminToolsDetails.Form.sfAdminToolsYearly.Form!Yearly_Order.SetFocus

DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdRecordsGoToNew
```

End Function

Comment: VB.NET is a different tag because it is a different dialect

Comment: Does the form have 'Allow Additions' set to TRUE?  Is the underlying recordset 'updatable'?

Comment: Yes. I actually have another button that will allow the user to switch to a new record. That command is in the sub form: sfAdminTools Yearly.

Comment: Are you trying to go to a new record on the main form or on a subform? The code you posted is on the 'main' form, thus the command would try to make that form go to a new record. If it's a case where you need to force the subform to commit the changes, this link answers that http://allenbrowne.com/bug-01.html

Answer (score 1):

The solution to my problem was a simple one: and kind of a rookie mistake on my part. I was not setting the focus to the form I was wanting to manipulate
Final code:

```
Me.fAdminToolsDetails.Form.sfAdminToolsYearly.Form.SetFocus
DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdRecordsGoToNew
```

Thank You for all your help

Answer (score 0):

it is because you try to add a new record to a form that is shown not from a table but from a select

change record source from "select from table"

to "table"

it is impossible to so insert into a select when using a remote database